# batを用いてcompositeで画像を合成したい

Tags: windows, batch-file

> 「composite」の合成コマンド
>       composite -compose over "素材画像名" "素体画像名" "出力画像名"

まず画像の名前一覧と素体の名前を取得して書き出します

```
(FOR %%A in (*_*_123.png) DO FOR %%B in (*.png) DO @echo composite -compose over "%%B" "%%A" "%%B") > temp.bat
```

結果

```
C:\hoge>FOR %B in (*.png) DO @echo composite -compose over "%B" "hoge_hoge_123.png" "%B" 
composite -compose over "hoge_hoge_123.png" "hoge_hoge_123.png" "hoge_hoge_123.png"
composite -compose over "hoge_hoge_124.png" "hoge_hoge_123.png" "hoge_hoge_124.png"
composite -compose over "hoge_hoge_125.png" "hoge_hoge_123.png" "hoge_hoge_125.png"
```

初めの改行とよく分からない一行と素体+素体の行、計三行が余分なので削除してそれを呼び出します

```
(FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=* usebackq" %%i IN ("temp.bat") DO @echo %%i) > "composite.bat
CALL "composite.bat"
```

結果

```
composite -compose over "hoge_hoge_124.png" "hoge_hoge_123.png" "hoge_hoge_124.png"
composite -compose over "hoge_hoge_125.png" "hoge_hoge_123.png" "hoge_hoge_125.png"
```

一応はこれで動作してくれるのですが
別のBATを書き出すだとか、書き出した結果を修正して実行させるだとか余りにも不格好です。
もう少し綺麗にしたいのですが、なにとぞご教授ください。

Comment: 素体？が複数存在する場合、どうすべきでしょうか？ 現状、最初の素体+素体の行以外を残してしまっているように見えます。

Comment: 画像の合成を目的としているので、初めの「素体+素体」以外の行は必要です。
また、素体が複数の場合を検討していませんでしたが、取り敢えずは考えないものとします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

素体が複数の場合を考えない、とのことですので`*_*_123.png`にマッチするのは１ファイルと言う前提で回答します。

`*.png`の中から`*_*_123.png`を除外すれば目的を達せられそうですので、`IF`で除外してはどうでしょうか？

```
FOR %%A IN (*_*_123.png) DO SET BODY=%%A
FOR %%B IN (*.png) DO (
    IF NOT "%%B"=="%BODY%" (
       ECHO composite -compose over "%%B" "%BODY%" "%%B"
    )
)
```

意図通りの出力が得られた場合、`ECHO`を削除することで直接コマンドを実行できますので、いったんファイルに出力するなどの処理は不要になります。

Comment: 確かに動作してくれました、ご丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます。